# Drop last part of URL with Nginx rewrite

Tags: nginx

If I have the following URL:

```
https://kl-office.com/directory
```

How can I configure Nginx to rewrite the above URL as:

```
https://kl-office.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
rewrite ^.*$ / permanent;
```

Although, this will rewrite **any** request to /